# JSON response with header and entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-jtable

I have a system that makes JSON responses like this. This is a list to use in a table. I have never seen this way of writing the field names first and then the data in another set?

Is this way of writing JSON data called something special?

I cannot figure how to read the response in my javascript/jQuery, does anyone have an example or google hint?

(anyone know if "jtable" can read it?)

```
         "WBEMLIST": {
            "header": [
                {
                    "name": "K9LBNR"
                },
                {
                    "name": "K9BEM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CBRUGER"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CDATO"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CTID"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UBRUGER"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UDATO"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UTID"
                }
            ],
            "entries": [
                [
                    1,
                    "Albert Einstein described\\the \"ork of theorists as making",
                    "WEBUSERFAU",
                    20140620,
                    114036,
                    "",
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    3,
                    "of reality is incomplete. Thus the concept that Einstein",
                    "WEBUSERFAU",
                    20140620,
                    114036,
                    "",
                    0,
                    0
                ],
              }
```

EDIT: I can easily read a list in javascript that i wrote like this in JSON, but not the above!:

```
{
"Bildlist": [
    {
        "K8LBNR": "1",
        "K8IMAG": "/HB0WKL3Q.PDF",
        "K8TYPE": "D",
        "K8LINKB": "",
        "CBRUGER": "WEBUSER",
        "CDATO": "2014.06.03",
        "CTID": "13.54.55"
    },
    {
        "K8LBNR": "1",
        "K8IMAG": "/HB0WKL3Q.PDF",
        "K8TYPE": "D",
        "K8LINKB": "",
        "CBRUGER": "WEBUSER",
        "CDATO": "2014.06.03",
        "CTID": "13.54.55"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: are you talking about jTable as the tag says (ie: the java swing component)? Are the jTable plugin from `http://www.jtable.org/`?

Comment: @Prashant - i know json. As you linked yourself, its not the same way of writing a json responce..

Comment: Your JSON is alsmost entirely valid. It's missing an opening curly brace before `"WBEMLIST"`, a closing curly brace at the end and you're missing one closing square bracket for the `"Entries"` array of arrays. What do you think is odd about this JSON?

Comment: @RobH - I know its not valid, the real question is what I mean is odd about this JSON.. Give me a minute to write an code responce to you

Comment: @AP87 Which bit do you think is odd? The nested arrays in `"entries"`? I don't see any reason why this format should be troubling you